# Plotting several curves in Matlab GUIDE in real time

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I need to plot 2 variables in the same axes in real time using the MATLAB GUIDE. Right now I´m successfully plotting 1 variable per subplot.

In order to do that I created in the _OpeningFcn a timer and 2 handles.plot:

```
handles.timer = timer(...
    'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...       % Run timer repeatedly
    'Period', 1, ...                        % Initial period is 1 sec.
    'TimerFcn', {@update_display,hObject}); % Specify callback function

handles.subplot=subplot(2,1,1,'Parent',handles.uipanel3);
handles.subplot1=subplot(2,1,2,'Parent',handles.uipanel3);

handles.plot = plot(handles.subplot,0,0,'b');
handles.plot1 = plot(handles.subplot1,0,0,'r');
```

Then, in the function update_display I concatenate the last values with the previous ones like this:

```
x = get(handles.plot,'XData');
x = [x, x(length(x))+1]; % (time=1sec)
y = get(handles.plot,'YData');
y = [y, yf]; % A/D value = yf

set(handles.plot,'XData',x);
set(handles.plot,'YData',y);

e = get(handles.plot1,'YData');
e = [e, error]; 
set(handles.plot1,'XData',x);
set(handles.plot1,'YData',e);
```

What I want to do is to plot in that same figure these 2 variables. I think that maybe I should change the handles.subplot with a previous handles.plot_parent with 'Parent' handles.uipanel3, but I'm having troubles configuring it, because I'm not sure which parameters it's expecting.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: You need to precise if you want to plot in the same `axes` or in a different one (still on the same figure) ?

Comment: ok, its in the same figure. I clarified it at the end of the question, but I just edited it and put it also at the beginning

Comment: ok let me rephrase, do you want every curve in the same **`subplot`**, or in a separate one  ?

Comment: OH! I want them in the same subplot (or plot if I just knew the configuration). I just want 1 figure (plot) with all the variables in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to start is probably to clear the confusion between plot/subplot/axes/figure etc ...

- A [`figure`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) is a "window". Graphic *object*, created with the similarly named command `figure`.
- An [`axes`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) is also a graphic *object*. It is a *container*, which can contains all sorts of other low level graphic objects like `lines`, `surfaces`, `patches` etc ... 
  It can contain more than one children object of more than one type. It can be created with the command `axes` or as you did with `subplot`. The specificity of `subplot` is that it allows you to easily position many `axes` in one figure. If you only plan to create a single `axes` in your figure, you do not need to call subplot, you can directly call `axes`.
- [`line`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) is the basic line graphic object. The properties can be modified to display a continuous line (with different styles), with or without markers, or even only markers, not necessarily "joined" by a line. The command `plot` does create a `line` object with the parameters you supply in input.

---

With that cleared up, let's solve your problem:

According to your comment, I understand you want all your plots (your `lines`), in the same "subplot" (eg: in the same `axes`).

You are almost there, you just need to define a single `axes` in your opening function, then modify the property of this `axes` so it can accept multiple lines (by default every new line erase the existing one). After that you initialize your lines as you did, then update them in the update function.

So in practice:

Replace the code under your timer definition by:

```
handles.axe = axes('Parent',handles.uipanel3,'NextPlot','Add'); %// c reate an "axes" object which can accept multiple plots

handles.plot0 = plot( handles.axe , 0,0 , 'b' ); %// create empty line in the axes "handles.axe"
handles.plot1 = plot( handles.axe , 0,0 , 'r' ); %// create empty line in the axes "handles.axe"
```

Then in your update function:

```
%// update your first line
y = get(handles.plot0,'YData');
y = [y, yf];        %// A/D value = yf
x = 0:numel(y)-1 ;  %// This will create a vector [0 1 2 3 ...] the same size as "y"

set(handles.plot0,'XData',x , 'YData',y ); %// you can set both XData and YData in the same instruction

%// update your second line
e = [ get(handles.plot1,'YData')  error ] ; %// you can concatenate the new value directly with the old data
set(handles.plot1,'XData',x ,'YData',e );
```

I took the liberty to alter a litle bit your update function, just to show you some other ways of doing things. Your initial way should work fine if you want to stick to it. The real trick was to create your 2 initial lines in the same `axes` object.

Comment: I cant thank you enough! I just started working with the Matlab GUIDE and I still get lost with some configurations. THANKS!